# Catch NETCONF Notification on ONOS

Tags: java, notifications, sdn, ietf-netconf, onos

I'm working on SDNs and trying so send data from SB to ONOS and I've used NETCONF as its protocol.

is ONOS able to get the message when my NETCONF agent sends notofication?

if yes, where does it save the messages and how can I access them?